# Connectivity of bipartite graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Consider $G(V,E)$ be a bipartite graph with $V_1$ and $V_2$ two parts :

$|V_1| = \binom{n}{k}$ and $|V_2| = \binom{n}{k+1}$ and

$\forall v \in V_1$ we have $\deg v = n-k$ and $\forall u \in V_2$ $\deg u = k + 1$.

After *Misha's* comment it's better to add some information. Actually $V_1$ is $[n]^i$ and $V_2 = [n]^{i+1}$, i.e. $[n]^i$ is $i$ elemented subset of $\{1 \dots n\}$. And $vu$ iff $v \subset u$ (for example $\{1 \dots i\} \subset \{1 \dots i , i + 1\}$, means there is edge between them)

How can we prove that $G$ is connected?

I tried to make some induction, but it failed in induction step. Don't know how to step back here. Any hints?

Comment: A graph is connected if and only if its vertices $V$ cannot be partitioned into $(S,T)$ where $S\cup T=V$, $S\cap T=\varnothing$, and for each $s\in S$, $t\in T$, $st\notin E$ (where $E$ is the edge set). Since all edges in a bipartite graph are of the form $uv$ where $u\in V_1$ and $v\in V_2$, the only candidate for such a partition is $(V_1, V_2)$. Show that this would be a contradiction.

Comment: You need to know more about the graph: what the edges are, and not just what the degrees of the vertices are.

Comment: @MishaLavrov we may say that's a graph induced by $V_1 = [n]^i$ and $V_2 = [n]^{i+1}$ , where $[n]^i$ is $i$ elemented subsets of $\{1, \dots n\}$. And there is edge iff $a \subset b$, $\forall a\in V_1$ and $b \in V_2$

Comment: @Math1000 I guess that's not true. Why can't we divide $V_1 = A_1 \cup A_2$  and $V_2 = B_1 \cup B_2$ such as $(A_1,B_1)$ and $(A_2,B,2)$ has no common edges. That's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to prove this is to show that if we take any two vertices $v,w$ in the graph, then there is a path to get from $v$ to $w$.

For this graph, it's enough to get from $v$ to $w$ assuming $v,w \in V_1$, because each vertex in $V_2$ has a neighbor in $V_1$.

I'd first consider a case where $v,w$ are disjoint sets. For example, $n=8$, $k=4$, $v=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $w = \{5,6,7,8\}$. Think about what a path would look like in this case.

That's probably the hardest single case to deal with, but it's not fully general, and it's not even necessarily possible for all $n$ and $k$. (If $k > \frac n2$, there are no disjoint pairs like this at all!) Still, once you find this path, you should be able to explain how to find any other path. (Just be sure not to use any elements of $[n]$ other than the ones found in $v \cup w$, because you can't assume that any such elements exist.)

Comment: So it's better to consider $u$ and $v$ in one part, then consider their common elements and then consider elements which will be bridges between them?

Comment: Consider a way from $v$ to $u$. Am I right that we should go down (or go up), then erase on of the elements, then add some element (which exists in $u$) and repeat it.

Comment: @openspace Yes, that's the idea.